# hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string, null given in Contact/BAO/Contact/Utils.php on line 232

Tags: contacts, joomla, 5.10.x

Has anyone else seen this error under Joomla and CiviCRM 5.10.4 when viewing a contact via the front end?

Warning: hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string, null given in /.../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact/Utils.php on line 232

Comment: Are you viewing the contact via a link that has "cs=" in the url?

Comment: Not that I am aware.  $inputCheck is null when validChecksum is called, CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('cs', 'String', $form, FALSE) returns a null value.

Comment: I'm having the same issue after upgrading to CiviCRM 5.13.12

Answer (score 0):

I am also receiving this error but on Wordpress 5.2.1 and civiCRM 5.13.4. I have not found a solution to this either.

Comment: I flagged this as an issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/issues/11, and it looks as thought it will be sorted in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Wordpress 5.2.1 and CiviCRM 5.13.4 too.
Changing line 232 to the following:

```
if (!hash_equals((string)$check, (string)$inputCheck)) {
```

in the file: civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\BAO\Contact\Utils.php
fixed the problem.